# How to get the current configuration of a thread pool via its HystrixThreadPoolKey?

Tags: java, hystrix

Is there a way to retrieve a `HystrixThreadPoolProperties` instance (or some other property container) specific to a `HystrixThreadPoolKey`?

So basically the default thread pool properties overlaid with my configuration provided by executing a command with:

```
HystrixCommand.Setter.withGroupKey(<some group>)
    .andThreadPoolKey(hystrixThreadPoolKey)
    .andThreadPoolPropertiesDefaults(...)
```

I've tried the following approach:

```
HystrixPropertiesStrategy hystrixPropertiesStrategy = HystrixPropertiesStrategyDefault.getInstance();

HystrixThreadPoolProperties hystrixThreadPoolProperties =
            hystrixPropertiesStrategy.getThreadPoolProperties(hystrixThreadPoolKey, HystrixThreadPoolProperties.Setter());
```

This seems to recover the [default Hystrix configuration](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#ThreadPool) for a threadpool but not any property changes I've made specific to the specific pool the key corresponds to.

This is the case even though I'm able to verify that the thread pool is indeed picking up the configuration when I execute commands that run from it.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Hystrix I am using is 1.5.0-rc.5, and I couldn't find anything from the library to allow direct retrieval of the threadpool properties associated with a command. So here is what I have tried using Java Reflection:

```
    HystrixInvokableInfo<?> command = HystrixRequestLog.getCurrentRequest().getAllExecutedCommands().iterator().next();

    Field field = command.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("threadPool");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    HystrixThreadPool threadPool = (HystrixThreadPool) field.get(command);

    Field field2 = HystrixThreadPool.HystrixThreadPoolDefault.class.getDeclaredField("properties");
    field2.setAccessible(true);
    HystrixThreadPoolProperties threadPoolProperties = (HystrixThreadPoolProperties) field2.get(threadPool);
```